# How to model invoice that can belong to either a person or a company?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails application I have *invoices* which can belong to either a *person* or a *company*. To make things even more complicated, a *person* can also belong to a *company*.

I figured that the right way to model this in Rails would be something like this:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoiceable, polymorphic: true
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices, as: :invoiceable
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices, as: :invoiceable
end
```

Is this the right way to do it?

And if so, can a *person* still belong to a *company* this way?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This seems right. What are you exactly looking for?

Comment: @Surya: Confirmation I guess :-)

Comment: the `Person` can't belong to a `Company` through the `Invoice`. since each individual `Invoice` only belongs to one `Person` or `Company`.  But a `Person` can belong directly to the `Company` if it has its own foreign key by adding `belongs_to :company` to it, and `has_many :people` to `Company`. the polymorphic association would not prevent other associations from being made

Comment: @MichaelGorman: This is exactly what I wanted to hear. Thanks a lot.